# clicking element closes lightbox and opens a hamburger menu in wix studios

Tags: velo

I am creating a hamburger menu in wix studios where in menu container I have placed images and text which opens a lightbox as a menu and I want a back button on the lightbox which closes the lightbox and opens the hamburger menu again.

I have tried adding a hamburger menu element which opens the menu container but it comes below the lightbox.